# Delphi - Format Filename from FTP

Tags: string, delphi, listview, split, format

okay, I've the following problem:

I like to get a list of all .txt files on my FTP Server in a special folder.
I solved this already.

```
 if IdFTP1.DirectoryListing.Count>0 then
          for i := 2 to IdFTP1.DirectoryListing.Count - 1 do
              with ListViewMain.Items.Add do
                Caption:=idftp1.DirectoryListing.Items[i].FileName;
```

But now, my .txt Files are like this:

> Projectname###Date###status.txt

I like to format the filename before loading into the ListView. After the ###'s the string should come into a Subitem.
So in the end it should look like this:

```
ListView Item = Projectname
ListView Subitem1 = Date
ListView SubItem2 = status
```

How can I do this?

Comment: Can be done with Copy and Pos or even better PosEx and solutions should be easily found by google

Answer (score 0):

Just use `Pos` and `Copy` to separate out the parts into separate parts, and then add them as you'd like:

EDIT: Fixed unintentional assignment to `i` within the loop (caused by copy/paste and then adding the `DirectoryListing` loop from the question to my answer). Declared new `j` variable to use for indexing into the strings.

```
var
  i, j: Integer;
  ProjName, ProjDate, ProjStatus: string;
  Temp: string;
begin
  // Other code here...
  for i := 2 to IdFTP1.DirectoryListing.Count - 1 do
  begin
    Temp := IdFTP1.DirectoryListing.Items[i].FileName;
    j := Pos('###', Temp);
    ProjName := Copy(Temp, 1, j - 1);
    System.Delete(Temp, 1, j + 2);    // Remove ProjName and three # chars
    j := Pos('###', Temp);
    ProjDate := Copy(Temp, 1, j - 1); // Grab project date
    ProjStatus := Copy(Temp, j + 3, Length(Temp));  // Grab status
    ProjStatus := ChangeFileExt(ProjStatus, '');   // Remove extension from filename
    with ListViewMain.Items.Add do
    begin
      Caption := ProjName;
      SubItems.Add(ProjDate);
      SubItems.Add(ProjStatus);
    end;
  end;
end;
```

Depending on your Delphi version, you can use `PosEx` to eliminate the call to `System.Delete`, but unless you're dealing with a lot of files or running this millions of times, it's probably fine to do the way it is here.

Comment: I've Delphi XE2 architect.

        i := Pos('###', Temp);
In this line Delphi give's me an error...

  
> 
>   C:\Users\User\Desktop\MyProject\Client\Rev 0.2 -
> Kopie\Unit1.pas(153,7): error E2081: E2081 Anweisung für
> FOR-Schleifenvariablen 'i'